# How to delete this cookie?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I found a cookie script that I am reviewing, it works to create the cookie but does not kill the cookie.

Code:

```
function SetCookie(cookieName,cookieValue,nDays) {
    var today = new Date();
    var expire = new Date();
 if (nDays==null || nDays==0) nDays=1;
   expire.setTime(today.getTime() + 3600000*24*nDays);
document.cookie = cookieName+"="+escape(cookieValue)
+ ";expires="+expire.toGMTString();
}

   function KillCookie(cookieName) {
      SetCookie(cookieName,"",-3);
   }

function ReadCookie(cookieName) {
   var theCookie=""+document.cookie;
   var ind=theCookie.indexOf(cookieName+"=");
if (ind==-1 || cookieName=="") return "";
var ind1=theCookie.indexOf(";",ind);
 if (ind1==-1) ind1=theCookie.length; 
return unescape(theCookie.substring(ind+cookieName.length+1,ind1));
}
```

As you see I created the function KillCookie which should set the expiration date back three days and have the browser automatically delete. Problem is its not deleting it.

I have these functions written in my code like so

```
 $(function() {
  $('#left').before('<div id="left_widg"><button></button></span>');
  $('#right').before('<div id="right_widg"><button></button></span>');

     $('#left_widg button').on('click',function() {    
       var _checkme = $('#left').css('display');
       var oriWidth = 180;
   if(_checkme === "block") {
     SetCookie('closeWidgetsLeft', 'true', 100);
    $('#left').animate({width:'-='+ oriWidth +'px'},500,function() {
      $(this).hide();
    $('#left_widg button').html('Open');
    });
   } else {
     KillCookie('closeWidgetsRight');
  $('#left').show();
  $('#left').animate({width:'+='+ oriWidth +'px'},500,function() {
  $('#left_widg button').html('Close'); 
});
}
});
if (ReadCookie('closeWidgetsLeft') == 'true') {
  $('#left').css('display','none');
 } else if (ReadCookie('closeWidgetsRight') == 'true') {
  $('#right').css('display','none');
   }
});
```

Comment: Maybe try changing the expire time in `KillCookie` to `(new Date().getTime() / 1000) - 1`? It might not be able to use times _before_ the Unix epoch. Also, `Date.getTime()` returns milliseconds, but cookie expire times use seconds.

Comment: Ok since I am new on cookies how would I write that? `KillCookie() { (new Date().getTime() / 1000) -1 }` or?

Comment: Inside `KillCookie` use `SetCookie(cookieName,"",(new Date().getTime() / 1000) - 1);` Try it and tell if it works or not.

Comment: Ok, I'll create a fiddle and try debug it...

Comment: Weird. Seems to work on my site. http://pietu1998.net/jscookie.html
I guess the bug is in the jQuery code, but I'm sorry I don't have time to examine it right now.

Comment: ok I'll keep playing around with it until then. Thanks for the help anyways Pietu

Comment: Just realised, `SetCookie(cookieName,"",-1);` is correct in the code due to the way you are coding the `SetCookie` function. Also try using `toUTCString()` in `SetCookie`. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
function KillCookie(key) {
    var t = new Date();
    t.setDate(t.getDate() - 1);

    document.cookie = [
            encodeURIComponent(key),
            '=',
            encodeURIComponent(String(null)),
            '; expires=' + t.toUTCString(),
            '; path=/'
    ].join('');
};
```

Note the path argument that sets the cookie for the root (the whole website). You should include it in the SetCookie function too...

```
function SetCookie(key,value,expires) {
    var t = new Date();
    t.setDate(t.getDate() + expires);
    document.cookie = [
            encodeURIComponent(key),
            '=',
            encodeURIComponent(String(value)),
            '; expires=' + t.toUTCString(),
            '; path=/'
    ].join('');
}
```

And KillCookie becomes :

```
function KillCookie(key) {
    SetCookie(key, null, -1);
};
```

*Sometimes dealing with cookies is tricky and many things can cause it to simply not work, so I would recommend you to use something like [this JQuery plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) from where this code is inspired.*

Comment: I'd just rather not use a plugin when javascript does itself. I jumped the gun and learned jQuery first so now I'm trying to keep going with Vanilla instead

Comment: No it's not a problem I appreciate the suggestion. I just believe that the jQuery way is a wasteful space really when javascript already has this. I have it work now, I believe the other javascript was making the cookies not work correctly. I don't remember.